# OpenVPN route successfully added but connection times out on http server

Tags: openvpn

I have an issue with setting up an OpenVPN connection on Windows 10

The issue does not happen with an Ubuntu installation.

Once the connection has been set up, the route gets added to the windows routes, however, when I try to reach one of the servers behind the VPN, I receive a timeout.

The firewall has been turned off, so there shouldn't be anything interrupting the connection, but I'm not able to figure out why the timeout happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in this case stemmed from an incorrectly configured server/client connection file causing multiple routes to be created.

It can be diagnosed with the command `route print`

The temporary workaround on the client side is to delete the existing routes and add a new one.

*Example*:

Client assigned IP: 192.168.31.12

Route after connection:

| Network Destination | Netmask | Gateway | Interface | Metric |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 192.168.31.0 | 255.255.255.0 | On-link | 192.168.31.1 | 291 |
| 192.168.31.0 | 255.255.255.0 | On-link | 192.168.31.12 | 281 |
| 192.168.31.0 | 255.255.255.0 | 192.168.31.0 | 192.168.31.12 | 25 |

Commands(in an elevated command prompt):

> route delete 192.168.31.0
>
> route add 192.168.31.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.31.10